# Prove that $\mathrm{E}[X\mid A] = \mathrm{E}[X]$ for an event $A$ independent of random variable $X$

Tags: probability, statistics

I am a novice at statistics. I have approached the problem in the following way:

$$\mathrm{E}[X\mid A] = (x_1\mid A \cdot P[x1\mid A] +  x_2\mid A \cdot P[x_2\mid A] + \ldots + x_k\mid A \cdot P[x_k\mid A])$$ ( using the definition of expectation )

$$\mathrm{E}[X\mid A]= (x_1P(x_1) + x_2P(x_2) + \ldots + x_kP(x_k))$$      ( As the event $A$ is independent of r.v $X$ )

$$\mathrm{E}[X\mid A]= \mathrm{E}[X]$$   ( using definition of expectation )

Am I thinking in the right direction? As I am very new to this topic, any hints or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry but this does not make a lot of sense to me. What is $x\mid A$ exactly?

Comment: it is conditional probability of random variable x given event A has occured.

Comment: No. What you said is $P(X=x\mid A)$. // At present your question is difficult to answer because of this kind of imprecision and because you are stating relevant **results** as if they were **definitions** (for example how do you know that E(X|A) is given by the second displayed formula?).